# How to assign 2 or + variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

sorry I'm french and I speak just few word in english.
I have a question maybe stupid :

Original code :`var test = {
commandChar : "!",
};`

```
    for (i = 0; i < commands.length; i++) {
    if (commands[i].hasOwnProperty('alt')) {
        for (j = 0; j < commands[i].alt.length; j++) {
            if ((index = text.toLowerCase().search(new RegExp("^\\" + test.commandChar + commands[i].alt[j].toLowerCase() + "\\b"))) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (index < 0) {
        index = text.toLowerCase().search("^\\" + "[" + test.commandChar + ",@#]" + commands[i].name.toLowerCase() + "\\b");
    }

    if (index > -1) {
        var command = text.slice(index).split(" ");
        if (!(commands[i].op || commands[i].elevated) || host || mod || authorised) {
            if (!(commands[i].mod) || host || mod) {
                commands[i].command(command, user);
            }
        }
        else {
            //sendChat("You have to be authorised to use " + commands[i].name + ".");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This is an little bot, example. 
If commandChar : "!". !help work but /help dont work. 
I want just use this commandChar with many symbole 
like
commandChar : "!", "/";

for use !help and /help

I think it should or array or regexpr

Sorry if I did not express myself properly it's complicated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do it but here's a quick one:

```
function isValidCommandChar(str) {
  return "!/.".indexOf(str.charAt(0)) > -1;
}

isValidCommandChar("!help");    // true
isValidCommandChar("#help");    // false
isValidCommandChar("/help");    // true
isValidCommandChar(".help");    // true
```

Comment: Thanks !! 
I'll test it